# Are Zond 2 and Venera 4 basically the same spacecraft design? What were the differences?

Tags: deep-space, soviet-union, venera, zond

The question [Which deep space spacecraft had main dish antennas that were perforated or made from mesh?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40298/12102) shows some images of [Venera 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_4), and there's one below.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39891/12102) to *When did ion propulsion first see some serious development efforts?* discusses [Zond 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zond_2) (image below as well) and at first they appear to have a lot of similarities.

**Question:** Are Zond 2 and Venera 4 basically the same spacecraft design? What were the differences? Was one adapted from the other?

---

[image]

**above:** Zond 2 [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Zond_2.jpg)

**below:** Venera 4 [source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Venera_4_%28MMA_2011%29_%281%29.JPG)

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Very short answer**

They are different generations of the same family of interplanetary spacecrafts.

**Short answer**

*Zond 2*, as well as Zond 1 and -3; and Venera 2 and -3, were interplanetary spacecrafts (in Soviet/Russian classification this category falls under "[automated interplanetary station](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)") of 3MV family [3MV English Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3MV) (in Russian "3МВ" [3МВ Russian Wikipedia page](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/3%D0%9C%D0%92); Russian version contains more information on launches). 3MV stands for "**3**rd generation of **M**ars-**V**enus interplanetary spacecrafts".

*Venera 4* was a derivative of Venera 3 (of 3MV series) spacecraft (and kind of "squeezed in between" 3MV and [4MV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4MV) series).

**Detailed answer**

Zond 2, as well as all other probes of 3MV series, was designed by [OKB-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energia_(corporation)) under Korolyov guidance, Venera 4 design was assigned to [NPO Lavochkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavochkin)

The major differences between Venera 4 and its predecessor are described in [this article](https://www.laspace.ru/projects/planets/venera-4/) (in Russian) from NPO Lavochkin webpage:

- Instrumentation compartment Temperature Control System was redesigned from scratch:
  (all following quotes are translated from Russian)

  > Instead of using gas and liquid system, the specialists of the Design Bureau of the S. A. Lavochkin Engineering Plant redesigned the temperature control system to work purely on gas; this was simpler in production and more reliable in operation. In this case, the radiator – cooler was combined with the central part of the parabolic pointed antenna.
- Total redesign of atmospheric entry module:

  > After the start of “Venera 3” the Academy of Sciences revised the model of the atmosphere of Venus and in the technical specifications for the [Venera 4] apparatus this has brought higher calculated values ​​of temperature (425 ° C versus 330-350 ° C for “Venera 3”) and pressure (1-10 atmospheres versus 1.5-5) at the surface of the planet, therefore the [atmospheric entry/lander-impactor] module had to be re-designed.
  >
  > [In order] to increase rigidity of the entry module, a gas pressure of 2 atmospheres was created inside the instrument compartment.
- Electrical power supply system for onboard equipment/instrumentation of orbital module was substantially redesigned.
- Substantial improvement of atmospheric entry module ablative heat shied:

  > Compared to Venera 3, thermal protection was significantly enhanced. To prevent heating of the apparatus during the descending phase, between the external thermal protection and the internal casing there was a multilayer thermal insulation made of fiberglass honeycombs with interlayers of asbestos textolite.
- 15% increase of the spacecraft mass:

  > The total mass of Venera 4 automatic station was 1106 kg. Since it was significantly larger in mass than Venera 3 (960 kg), instead of the 8K78 (Molniya) rocket the modernized 8K78M launcher (Molniya-M) was used instead.

P.S. The last mentioned [article](https://www.laspace.ru/projects/planets/venera-4/) contains quite a bit more of technical information on  Venera 4, although not explicitly stated whether those details were a change from Venera 3 or not. Although the page is written in Russian, google translate these days does a pretty good job.